# Get MethodBase for test method in TestInitialize

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

In my setup before the test I want to get the actual test method so I can get an attribute that is attached to it. I do not want to call MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() at the start of every test. How can I solve this?

```
[TestInitialize]
public void setUp()
{
    MethodBase _Method = (MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    CurrentTestCaseId = GetAttribute(_Method);
    Log.Info("Starting to execute Test Case ID: " +CurrentTestCaseId);        
}

[TestMethod()]
[TestCategory("UserLogin")] 
[TestId("TC26828")]
public void TestUserLogin()
{
    GetPageFactory().GetLoginPage(Driver).logUserIntoApplication("bob", "bob");
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4.5+, you can use the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` to help get the name of the method. You can use that to get the `MethodInfo` which can get you access to the attributes of the method.

```
public void Setup([CallerMemberName] string method = null)
{
     Type type = typeof(MyTestClass);
     MethodInfo info = type.GetMethod(name);
     CurrentTestCaseId = GetAttribute(info);
     Log.Info("Starting to execute Test Case ID: " +CurrentTestCaseId); 
}

[TestId("someID")]
public void MyTest()
{
    Setup(); //"method" should be automatically provided as "MyTest"
}

public TestIdAttribute GetAttribute(MethodInfo info)
{
    return (TestIdAttribute)info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestIdAttribute), false).First();
}
```